# DR for Azure SQL DB/Synapse

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

We have enabled LTR backup for Azure SQL DB's and Geo Backup policy is by default enabled in Synapse.

Below are my queries:

1. Does the LTR backup for Azure SQL DB's and Geo Backup in Synapse are created in a regional pair or in a Geo redundant location?
   Lets say my DB/Synapse is in North Europe region and the entire Europe region is down, is it possible for me the restore the DB/Synapse backup in a server created in a different location like US.

Note -- We do not want to setup an active Geo redundant Geo replication

2. Is it possible to extract the backups of Azure SQL DB and Azure Synapse into a storage location of our choice (either via PowerShell or any other automated way)

Answer (score 0):

1. Azure SQL DB has an option called [Backup Storage Redundancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?view=azuresql#backup-storage-redundancy) which can take the following values: LRS, ZRS, RA-GRS, RA-GZRS. This option replicates DB backups depending on the selected redundancy. With the RA-GRS option, backups are replicated to paired geo regions. In case the region that contains DB is down(North EU in your case), the backup replicated to [paired region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/cross-region-replication-azure?toc=%2Fazure%2Fsynapse-analytics%2Fsql-data-warehouse%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fsynapse-analytics%2Fsql-data-warehouse%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json#azure-cross-region-replication-pairings-for-all-geographies) (West EU) can be used to perform restore using [Geo-restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/recovery-using-backups?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal#geo-restore). This backup can be restored to a server in any region like US Central, US East, etc.
2. [Geo-backups in Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/backup-and-restore#geo-backups-and-disaster-recovery) also use the paired region for backup replication.
3. In Azure SQL DB it is not possible to extract the backups into a storage location of user’s choice.